# extracting the common prefixes from a list of strings

Tags: c#, string

I have a list of strings, such as:

```
{ abc001, abc002, abc003, cdef001, cdef002, cdef004, ghi002, ghi001 }
```

I want to get all the common unique prefixes; for example, for the above list:

```
{ abc, cdef, ghi }
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What about this set: `{abc, abd, abcd, abd, ad}` what's the common prefixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var list = new List<String> {
    "abc001", "abc002", "abc003", "cdef001",
    "cdef002", "cdef004", "ghi002", "ghi001"
};
var prefixes = list.Select(x = >Regex.Match(x, @"^[^\d]+").Value).Distinct();
```

Comment: I don't know your code do what but I know you at most pick `n` prefix, but it can be more than `n` prefix, see my comment on question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using Regular Expression to select the text part, and then use `HashSet<string>` to add that text part so no duplication added:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


//simulate your real list 
List<string> myList = new List<string>(new string[] { "abc001", "abc002", "cdef001" });   

string pattern = @"^(\D*)\d+$";
//  \D* any non digit characters, and \d+ means followed by at least one digit,
// Note if you want also to capture string like "abc" alone without followed by numbers
// then the pattern will be "^(\D*)$"

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

HashSet<string> matchesStrings = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (string item in myList)
{
    var match = regex.Match(item);

    if (match.Groups.Count > 1)
    {
        matchesString.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```

result:

```
abc, cde
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea to write a helper class to represent your data. For example:

```
public class PrefixedNumber
{
    private static Regex parser = new Regex(@"^(\p{L}+)(\d+)$");

    public PrefixedNumber(string source) // you may want a static Parse method.
    {
        Match parsed = parser.Match(source); // think about an error here when it doesn't match
        Prefix = parsed.Groups[1].Value;
        Index = parsed.Groups[2].Value;
    }

    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
}
```

You need to come up with a better name, of course, and better access modifiers.

Now the task is quite easy:

```
List<string> data = new List<string> { "abc001", "abc002", "abc003", "cdef001",
                                       "cdef002", "cdef004", "ghi002", "ghi001" };
var groups = data.Select(str => new PrefixedNumber(str))
                 .GroupBy(prefixed => prefixed.Prefix);
```

The result is all data, parsed, and grouped by the prefix.

Comment: I know. This might be an overkill.

Comment: @Saeed - That's an imagined problem that the OP never suggested. Following that logic, you might as well solve the problem by returning `""`, or all first letters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your prefix is all alpha characters and terminited by the first non-alpha character, you could use the following LINQ expression

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<String>() 
  { "abc001d", "abc002", "abc003", "cdef001", "cdef002", "cdef004", "ghi002", "ghi001" }; 

var prefixes = (from s in listOfStrings
                select new string(s.TakeWhile(c => char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray())).Distinct();
```