# Extracting common prefixes from list of strings in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to do something similar to this ([extracting the common prefixes from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213836/extracting-the-common-prefixes-from-a-list-of-strings)) in java. Where List of strings are file paths 

`Eg:
List filePaths1 = new ArrayList();

filePaths1.add("/root/test1/asass");

filePaths1.add("/root/test1");

filePaths1.add("/root/test");

filePaths1.add("/root/test/aaa/");

filePaths1.add("/root/test/bbb/ccc");

filePaths1.add("/root/test/fff/");

filePaths1.add("/root/test/eee/asasa/");

filePaths1.add("/root/rahul/e?ee/asasa/");

filePaths1.add("/root/rahul/asasa/");

filePaths1.add("/root/rahul/no*tthis/asasa/**");

filePaths1.add("/etc/rahul/test");`

Want to implement a function which will return a list of following strings if we pass above list to it.

`{"/root/test1", "/root/test", "/root/rahul", "/etc/rahul/test"}`

It should compare each string with another, In above case 
if we consider 2 strings "/root/test1/asass" and "/root/test1", it has the longest common prefix as /root/test1 so we will add it to output list, if there was any other string which is starting with /root/test1, it will be represented by /root/test1.

Next to it as there are five strings which are starting with /root/test, output list will contain /root/test as these 5 strings are having longest common prefix as "/root/test".

Likewise there is only 1 String having a pattern /etc/rahul/test, which is not sharing or starts with any other pattern defined so it will be added as it is,

Can we do this using regular expression? Any suggestions would be really helpful. Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: I think your definition of 'common prefixes' is not clear. Why `"/root"` is not a common prefix? And why not `"/"` which is the common prefix of all the strings you mentioned? Please explain your definition of common prefixes in details.

Comment: Its basically a longest common prefixes.

Comment: @RahulBorkar: in your example, why is `"/etc/rahul"` a _common_ prefix? It's only there once.

Comment: @jlordo Because its there after all and this should be included.

Comment: @RahulBorkar: Using your argument, `"/etc/rahul/te"` should be in the result list also.

Comment: @jlordo "/etc/rahul/test" should be there as its a unique common path in input filepaths list...

Comment: @RahulBorkar: `"/root/test/bbb/ccc"` is also unique. Why's that not in the list?

Comment: @jlordo, because there is common prefix to it as "/root/test" in the list or in other string in the list. another example for this would be there are also 3 paths as "/root/rahul/e?ee/asasa/", "/root/rahul/asasa/" and "/root/rahul/no*tthis/asasa/**", which are having common sub path as "/root/rahul/"

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense to me. Using your argument again, `"/etc/rahul/test"` and `"/root/rahul/e?ee/asasa/"` also have a common prefix: `"/"`. Actually, `"/"` is the longest common prefix of all of your inputs.

Comment: @jlordo, I guess we are talking about longest common prefix here...

Comment: The main problem is: Nobody understands the rule, why this input leads to that output. As long as this is not clear nobody will try to answer the question.

Comment: @RahulBorkar jlordo is right, the longest common prefix is "/"

Comment: So guys guide me, how it should be asked, I have given the input strings and output strings, I can post the code I have implemented till now if you guys want.

Comment: The code would be good (to show you made some effort). But you have to make clear (in words) what are the rules for the output.

Comment: Added more details to question

Comment: @RahulBorkar: Still very unclear. In your new example `"/root/test"` is a prefix of `"/root/test1"`, so why should both be in the result list?

Comment: @jlordo, as its a file path and /root/test and /root/test1 are 2 different directories, there are 2 distinct paths.

Comment: @RahulBorkar: now we're getting closer... How do you distinguish  between file and folder?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32746/discussion-between-rahul-borkar-and-jlordo)

Answer (score 1):

## Description

If I understand you correctly you're looking for a way to identify the largest common denominator of each folder in a list. I see that you're providing a large list of folders and you want to sieve through all the entries and return only the largest. That additional handling logic is beyond the scope of this expression.

So given:

```
/root/test1/aaaaa
/root/test2/bbbbb
/root/test3/ccccc
```

You would expect `/root/` to be the common folder to all entries.

Whereas given:

```
/root/test1/aaaaa
/root/test1/bbbbb
/root/test1/ccccc
```

You would expect `/root/test1/` to be the common folder.

This regex will find the those largest denominators in the samples above. You could use this to itterate through all your values, matching them and building an array of the results based on your desired logic.

`^(\/.*(?=[\/\n\r])).*[\r\n]*(?:^(?=\1).*?[\r\n]*)*\Z`

[image]

Note: I'm using the case insensitive option to keep the examples easy, you'd want to remove this if running on a *nix system which differentiates uppercase and lower case at the file level. Also using this expression does require the multiline option such as:

```
Pattern re = Pattern.compile("^(\\/.*(?=[\\/\\n\\r])).*[\\r\\n]*(?:^(?=\\1).*?[\\r\\n]*)*\\Z",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

## Not Clear in the OP

What isn't real clear is how do you want to handle a list like:

```
/root/test1/test2/test3/aaaaa
/root/test1/test2/bbbbb
/root/test1/ccccc
```

Comment: it should return  /root/test1

Answer (score 1):

## Description

After reviewing the detailed chat window I see you have this sample text from M Buettner:

```
(diverging at level 1) 
/root/abc/foo 
/etc/def/bar 
would give two entries 

(diverging at level 2) 
/root/abc/foo 
/root/def/foo 
would give two entries 

(diverging at level 3 and beyond) 
but 
/root/abc/def/ghi 
/root/abc/klm/nop 
would give only one entry? (/root/abc/)
```

It looks like you want each unique string from the start of a string to the third `/`

This powershell [sorry I don't know java well enough] does return the unique values.

```
$folders = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$null = $folders.add("/root/test1/asass")
$null = $folders.add("/root/test1")
$null = $folders.add("/root/test")
$null = $folders.add("/root/test/aaa")
$null = $folders.add("/root/test/bbb/ccc")
$null = $folders.add("/root/test/fff")
$null = $folders.add("/root/test/eee")
$null = $folders.add("/root/rahul/e?ee/aaaaa")
$null = $folders.add("/root/rahul/aaa")
$null = $folders.add("/root/rahul/no*tthis/aaaaa")
$null = $folders.add("/root/rahul/test")
$null = $folders.add("/etc/rahul/test")

Write-Host "------"

$Output = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    [regex]::Match($folder, "^(\/(?:.*?(?:\/|$)){0,2})", "Multiline") | foreach {
        # found a match set
        $null = $Output.add($_.Groups[1].Value)
        } # next match
    } # next folder


$Output | select -unique
```

**Returns**

```
/root/test1/
/root/test1
/root/test
/root/test/
/root/rahul/
/etc/rahul/
```